# Where do I find the fishing rod?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

Yesterday, I learned of the fishing minigame in Chantelise. However, I'm fighting the last boss already and haven't heard anything about fishing yet. Googling this, I determined that I need to get the fishing rod item to be able to fish...however, it's not mentioned anywhere how to obtain this fishing rod.

Where do I find the fishing rod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get your first Fishing Rod by **returning to the Plains stage at any point after Chapter 3 ends**. In her Chapter 4 dialogue, Aira will mention, if you talk to her, that there is a fisherman that has been at the Plains.

You'll need to either play through the tutorial in full, or do a time trial of the 3rd section. Either way, right to your left you'll see a fisherman!

[image: Fisherman]

Talk to him and he'll eventually give you the **Teacher's Pole**. If you talk to him a few more times, he'll also teach you how to engage in proper man-to-fish combat.